# copy the contents of a local directory to a directory in hdfs

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have got a requirement that I should be able to copy the contents of a directory from local system to a directory on HDFS.

The condition is only the directory contents should be copied to the location I have specified, not the source directory itself. Using command `copyfromlocal` I can achieve this. But I need to use Java. There is this method `copyFromLocalFile` which should be used for making a copy from local file system, the problem is it copies the directory itself. Also tried using `FileUtils.copy` method, gives the same result as the `copyFromLocalFile`

As a test I tried to copy directory contents from a test directory to another directory , both on the local file system. I used `FileUtils.copyDirectory`. This works but I cannot use it for HDFS. I have seen many links to related to this same question but could not find any way.

Guys, could you please let me know if this is possible or not or is it some design flaw? If this is possible how can I proceed ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ya it's really hard to get things done with `FileSystem` api exactly the way you want. Insufficient documentation makes things even harder(Too many methods, little explanation). I faced the same problem an year ago.

The only solution I got is iterative :

```
void copyFilesToDir(String srcDirPath, FileSystem fs, String destDirPath)
        throws IOException {
    File dir = new File(srcDirPath);
    for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
        fs.copyFromLocalFile(new Path(file.getPath()),
                new Path(destDirPath, file.getName()));
    }
}
```

I think the code needs little explanation.

Comment: Thanks Sir, the code works like a charm!!! I was banging my head to get a solution and was thinking to go with creating new folders each time I do a upload. Though I have noticed something, not sure if it has got something to my system. I can see that in the folder in hdfs along with the filename there is another file with a tilde(~) sign. Is this something I should be worried about ?

Comment: It might be some temp file inside the source dir. Try `ls -a` in that dir, since `listFiles` considers hidden file too.

Comment: yeah, you are right!!! I exported the folder from hdfs to a loca directory and checked that the files with tilde sign are not there. Again the size of those files in hdfs shows to be 0.

Comment: if u don't want to move hidden files, a `FileFilter` has to be used  to `listFiles` method with check `File.isHidden` or any condition you want.

Comment: Thanks Sir, for the idea, I have used a filter to not to include the files ending with a "~" sign and the issue is resolved.